# Chrome won't open iTunes desktop links

Tags: itunes, google-chrome

I used to be able to click through to the iTunes App Store on my Mac by clicking a link in Chrome, but now it just hangs on a "Connecting to the iTunes Store..." page. What to do?

Comment: itmss appears to no longer be in Local State. Or at least it's not in there for me. Tested with 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your Chrome user data:

- On Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
- On Windows: `C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`

In the `Local State` file, remove the entry between commas that mentions `itmss` (e.g., `"itmss":true,`)—this will reset the iTunes link handler. Now you can check "Remember my choice" the next time Chrome goes to open an iTunes link.

Answer (score 3):

As of Chrome 58 on macOS, this setting is in a file called `Preferences` in the relevant profile folder for your Chrome application files. In other words, something along the lines of:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile1/Preferences`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile2/Preferences`

depending on whether or not you have multiple user profiles and which one you are using.

Inside that file, search for `itmss` and change the entry to false so that Chrome opens iTunes links, in other words:

`"itmss":false,`

The equivalent entry for the Mac AppStore is `macappstores`, i.e.:

`"macappstores":false,`

Before making this change, be sure to:

- quit Chrome
- make a copy of the original file in case things get messed up